# Freeform multiple file upload, only one appears in review/edit form

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads

I'm using Freeform Pro v.4.0.12.  My form submits a to a review page so that user can edit their form data.

I'm using 2 file upload fields and both files are successfully uploading.  However, on the review page, only one file appears.  Any idea why or what I can do to make the 2nd file upload field editable?

Thanks!

Peter T

I saw this other post below, but since both my files are uploading, I don't think it applies to my issue.

[Other post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16682/freeform-4-x-doesnt-upload-files-but-no-error-occurs/16683#16683)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Freeform 4.x doesn't upload files but no error occurs](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16682/freeform-4-x-doesnt-upload-files-but-no-error-occurs)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the other post was a big help and answered my question!