# Freeform file upload not in database table

Tags: solspace-freeform

Does anyone know why the filename or names do not always record in the freeform table?
Ex. my form is located in exp_freeform_form_entries_1.
the file field is form_field_22.
But on many of my forms, this field is blank.

I'm using ff pro v.4.0.12

My code is below

```
        <p><label for="file_field0">Please upload your file: (File format: .docx or .pdf)</label>
                <input type="file" id="file_field0" name="file_field0[0]" class="required" /></p>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Peter T

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm just about there.   I was trying to combine multiple uploads into one field.  So I am now using two file upload fields and the fields were successfully entered into the form database table.

My issue now is that on the update form (exp:freeform:edit), I am only able to view one of the files.  My code is below:

```
    <fieldset>                    
    <p><label for="380"><strong>Statement of Interest</strong>: (File format: .docx or .pdf)</label>
            {freeform:field:file_statement show="1"}</p>

    <p><label for="379"><strong>Transcript</strong>: (File format: .docx or .pdf)</label>
            {freeform:field:file_transcript show="1"}</p>

        <input type="hidden" name="completed" id="completed" value="Yes">
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" /></p>

</fieldset>
```

I can't find documentation that states how to view and update multiple files on the freeform:edit form.
Any help is appreciated.
Peter T

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more of your template code? Does a file get uploaded? Are you saying that it works sometimes?

Im not sure why your name attribute has the '[0]'

I have a form and the input looks like this:

```
<p><strong>Attach file:</strong><span class="required_field">*</span>  <input type="file" name="file1" class="required" accept="doc|docx"/><br/>5 MB max. MS Word format .doc or .docx</p>
```

Comment: Are you using freeform pro v4.0.12? This code didn't work for me.

I use the file[0] code based on this post (http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16682/freeform-4-x-doesnt-upload-files-but-no-error-occurs) and it works every now and then. Meaning that the filename is entered into the form database (exp_freeform_form_entries_1) But more often the column in this db is empty. The file is uploaded into the exp_freeform_file_uploads table.

Weird.